# How can I use jQuery and/or CSS3 to change how many unordered list items are displayed?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, css-animations

Hey fine folks of Stack Overflow.

I have a bunch of unnested, unordered list items. They look like this:

[image: my list items]

I want the user to be able to increase or decrease (preferably with a nice animation) the number of these list items that are displayed on the page, say, via + and - buttons. How can I best do this with jQuery and/or CSS3?

[Here is my Mako template and linked CSS file](http://jsfiddle.net/7YrMv/), as requested.

Comment: Can you post the HTML/CSS you  have so far as a jsFiddle?

Comment: @Chandu it's a mako template, but yes, I can :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this. It's fairly rudimentary, but it works-ish.

http://jsfiddle.net/CnKXK/

Comment: Here's a version with your stuff. It's a little glitchy, but it gives you the main idea. http://jsfiddle.net/7YrMv/1/

Comment: This definitely works! Thanks :) I'll try to add some animation later.